# cakephp condition based on joined table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
 $results = $this->Cart->find('all', 
        array(
          'contain' => array(
              'Product' => array(
                  'Category' => array(
                      'conditions' => array('Category.name LIKE' => "%$query%"),
                      'fields' => array('Category.name')
                   )
              )
           ),
          'conditions'=>array(
              'Product.title LIKE' => "%$query%"
          ),                                                  
         'fields'=> array('Product.title')
        );
```

This is query example, I want only get results if products contain at least one entry ?

Now if product not contains product I'm getting something like:

```
array(){
'field' => 'value'
'Product' => 'Category' => array()
}
```

I'm at at all not want get product without categories, how I cant add that to condition ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $results = $this->Cart->find('all', 
                            array(
                                'contain' => array(
                                    'Product' => array(
                                        'Category' => array(
                                            'conditions' => array('Category.name LIKE' => "%$query%"),
                                            'fields' => array('Category.name')
                                        )
                                    )
                                ),
                                'conditions'=>array(
                                        'Product.title LIKE' => "%$query%"
                                ),                                                  
                                'fields'=> array('Product.title')
                            )
                        );
```

you forget one bracket to close....may be its work for you....